# I need to find a file in directory and copy it to a different directory

Tags: php, file, subdirectory

I merely have the file name, without extension (.txt, .eps, etc.)
The directory has several subfolders. So, the file could be anywhere.

How can I seek the filename, without the extension, and copy it to different directory?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know the extension? What would happen if you wanted to copy `text.txt` but the program found and copied `text.doc`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860393/recursive-file-search-php

Comment: that's actually a good point. what if the file name is unique?

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php and http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php and http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: I tried it out, it can't find my network drive. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+recursive+file

Comment: It can't find network drives:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(X:\apps)... failed to open dir: No such file or directory'

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/preg_find.php.txt seems to be exactly what you need, to find the file. then just use the normal php copy() command http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

as for seeking filenames, could use a database to log where the files are? and use that log to find your files

Comment: i need to find the file first in the directory.

For example: I have the file name: iamfile01.
I need to find it first...

I know it is on hard drive X: but no idea in which directory it could be in.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) is the fastest method for such operations:

```
function findRecursive($folder, $file) {
    foreach (scandir($folder) as $filename) {
        $path = $folder . '/' . $filename;
        # $filename starts with desired string
        if (strpos($filename, $file) === 0) {
            return $path;
        }
        # search sub-directories
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            $result = findRecursive($path);
            if ($result !== NULL) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For copying the file, you can use [`copy()`](http://php.net/copy):

```
copy(findRecursive($folder, $partOfFilename), $targetFile);
```