# How to find the files in different folders by using php?

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the `php` file structure.

I want to run a script to genearte images of bunch of `pdf` files.

My problem is the actually `pdf` files are in different folders and structures.

For example:

a pdf could locate in

```
/test/book/pdf/test.pdf.
```

another one could be in

```
/server/pdfs/link/dummy.pdf.
```

There are thousands of `pdfs` file in the file system and I am using `Imagick` to generate the images from `pdfs`.

I am not sure how to locate all of the `pdf` nor how to specify the file path in `imagick` constructor.

```
 $im = new imagick('file path to pdf here');  //I don't know how to specify the file path here...
 $im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
```

Can anyone gives me a hint? Thanks so much!

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1860393/

Answer (score 1):

You could go up to the root folder and scan all the directories and their subdirectories for .pdf files and store them in an array (PHP: scandir), an array or a string with a caracter-delimiter between each filename.