# Deleting files matching a specific file extension recursivly?

Tags: php

I would like to delete all files matching a particular extension in a specified directory and all subtree. I suppose I should be using using unlink but some help would be highly appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: yes `unlink()` will help you for deleting files and `Delete` will help, deleting directories :)

Comment: this might help you - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334398/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-contents-using-php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a combination of this

[Recursive File Search (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860393/recursive-file-search-php)

And the `unlink` / `delete`

You should be able to edit the example instead of echoing the file, to delete it

Answer (score 0):

To delete specific extension files from sub directories, you can use the following function. Example:

```
<?php 
function delete_recursively_($path,$match){
   static $deleted = 0,
   $dsize = 0;
   $dirs = glob($path."*");
   $files = glob($path.$match);
   foreach($files as $file){
      if(is_file($file)){
         $deleted_size += filesize($file);
         unlink($file);
         $deleted++;
      }
   }
   foreach($dirs as $dir){
      if(is_dir($dir)){
         $dir = basename($dir) . "/";
         delete_recursively_($path.$dir,$match);
      }
   }
   return "$deleted files deleted with a total size of $deleted_size bytes";
}
?>
```

e.g. To remove all text files you can use it as follows:

```
<?php echo delete_recursively_('/home/username/directory/', '.txt'); ?>
```